# bugzilla installation using xampp

Tags: xampp, bugzilla

I want to know the installation steps for bugzilla using xampp. Where do I need to configure the file so that I can access it as a localhost?

I have the bugzilla tar file with me and xampp in installed in my system. It is showing the below error:

> Can't locate Math/Random/ISAAC.pm in @INC (@INC contains: . lib D:/xampp/perl/site/lib D:/xampp/perl/vendor/lib D:/xampp/perl/lib) at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 13.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/RNG.pm line 13.
>   Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 28.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Util.pm line 28.
>   Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Install/Localconfig.pm line 22.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Install/Localconfig.pm line 22.
>   Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Install/Filesystem.pm line 22.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Install/Filesystem.pm line 22.
>   Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 15.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 15.
>   Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla.pm line 21.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla.pm line 21.
>   Compilation failed in require at D:/xampp/htdocs/bugzilla/index.cgi line 19.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at D:/xampp/htdocs/bugzilla/index.cgi line 19.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SELinux running and all of the modules installed, you may have to restore the security contexts for the web folder. For instance:

> restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/bugzilla